# The system behind automatically logging users in to your site

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security

Using ASP.NET MVC, Entity framework, jQuery. I want to give users the ability to automatically log in if they have clicked "Remember me", The approach I've come up with is:

1. When a user logs in

   - Hash PW and store in DB
     if when the user logs in & they tick 'remember me'
   - Create a cookie, with a encrypted UserID then some sort of separator and the hashed PW.

Then the next time the user comes back, I can check for their cookie, and if it exists I log them in with AJAX. If the user logs out I of course delete their cookie.

Is this the correct way to accomplish the automatic log in functionality?

I guess my hashing function and User ID encrypting func will be server side, and to create the cookie I'll call that function via AJAX, then create it.

Is this best practice?

Thankyou

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach (having a cookie with a value indicating the user is logged in) is fairly standard.

What is *not* standard is storing the hashed username and password (in particular the password) - not sure why you would need to and since cookies are transmitted in clear text (for http connections), you are giving anyone between your site and the user the ability to see the password hash and a chance to break it in order to get the password.

Instead of a password hash, create a unique "loggedIn" token (say a GUID) that you store in the cookie - this is what you compare to in order to determine whether a user is logged in.

Comment: Ok I think see what you are saying. So I create a GUID & the user stores that in a client-side cookie. When he/she logs in (automatically) I match that against the Database and if there's a row in my SQL table e.g user_auth_guds, where the guid key matches, I log the user in? And if they logout, I just delete their client side cookie?

Comment: @Baconbeastnz - Sounds about right. It is about exposing sensitive information. I would also clear the token value from the Database when the user logs out/forgets the password, so it can't be reused if captured.

Answer (score 1):

One of the many possible approaches could be:

Note: I have coded it in Pure PHP. But the logic would be same in all languages.

1. set $redirect = FALSE.
2. Is $_GET["logout"] set? If yes, go to 3, otherwise go to 5
3. If set, delete, auth,rem_me cookies, destroy session.
4. Show login form and exit.
5. Is this a post request? If yes, go to 6, otherwise go to 18
6. Set $redirect = TRUE.
7. Is Username & Password supplied? if yes, go to 8, otherwise go to 3
8. Get $username, $pass-hash & $rem-me-hash from db.
9. Is $username & $password same as in DB? If yes, go to 10, otherwise go to 3
10. Set cookie["username"] = sanitized($_POST["username"])
11. Issue a cookie["auth"] containing $auth = sha1(username.password.time.6random_letters).
12. Set A Session["auth"] = sha1($auth). Unset $auth.
13. Is remember me option selected? if yes, go to 13, otherwise go to 15
14. Set $rem = sha1($user_string.$time.$password.$username.$random)
15. Set cookie["rem"] = $rem
16. Set $rem = 0
17. If $rem != $rem-me-hash_DB, insert $rem in DB. Go to 23
18. Is $rem cookie set? Yes go to 19, else go to 20
19. Is $rem cookie == $rem-hash-in-db? if yes, go to 22, else go to 3
20. Is $username-cookie && $auth-cookie &&auth-SESSION set? If yes, go to 21, else go to 3
21. Is sha1($auth-cookie) === $_SESSION["auth"]? If yes, go to 22, else go to 3
22. Is $redirect == TRUE? If yes, redirect back to this same page with 301, GET method. else go to 23
23. Here is my super-secret Star-Trek Wallpapers(content).

A long process, but (hopefully) covers all scenarios.

Save all this algorithm in a `password.php` and on top of every file you want to protect, include this file. The control to secret content will come only if it goes through all the possible scenarios. At every fault, the script will show the login form & exit.

Also it implements the Post-Redirect-Get (*[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)*) approach, where you get a POST request, process it, and redirect the user back with a GET method, to prevent the double-form submissions on Back & Refresh button presses..

There may be a typos or mixed-concept in the above description. Let me know about any improvements.